# picture layout changes from one screen size to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I just developed a application which has various pictures, here it is.
[image]

however when I launch the application in another pc with a larger screen, this is what happens:

[image]

the two side bars start overlapping one another, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: c# windows forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Control.Anchor` and `Control.Dock` properties to manage each controls position.

The default anchor setting for a control when placed on a form in Visual Studio is "Top, Left".  you should also set anchor for your other right side controls. for example: set anchor for `Bottom` and `Right`

```
PictureBox1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
```

For more information about How to Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties, please take a look at: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/